# Catch Complete Within RxJS Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable which just complete in case if the process is canceled.

I'm trying to use that observable in another observable pipe with a switchMap() in a recursive way.

I would like to "catch" the complete within the pipe.

Here is an example:

```
function removeComponent(path: string): Observable<any> {
    ...
    // This method returns an observable with some result if the component is removed.
    // But, just complete in some cases.
}

function removeMultipleComponent(paths: string[]): Observable<string> {
    if (paths.length > 1) {
        return removeComponent(path[0]).pipe(


            // I would like to catch the complete here.


            switchMapTo(
                of(paths[0]),
                removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1))
            )
        );
    }
    return removeComponent(path[0]);
}
```

Is there any way to catch an observable complete within the pipe()?

**Update: Solution based on Hodossy Szabolcs comment**

```
function removeMultipleComponent(paths: string[]): Observable<string> {
    if (paths.length > 1) {
        return removeComponent(path[0]).pipe(
            defaultIfEmpty('random text'),
            switchMap((value) => {
                if (value === 'random text') {
                    return removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1));
                } else {
                    return merge(
                        of(paths[0]),
                        removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1))
                    );
                }
            })
        );
    }
    return removeComponent(path[0]);
}
```

Comment: I know that I can write a custom Observable and I can catch the complete within that, but I think this way is safer and clear (also less code).

Comment: you've mentioned that it can be canceled. how is it got cancelted in your app?

Comment: Within the first observable there are 2 subjects that are connected to 2 buttons. after the user clicked on the "cancel" button, I just return with an empty of() observable.

Comment: i mean, there is a `subscribe` somewhere in the application. do you `unsusbscribe` from it?

Comment: Yes, I subscribe to the removeMultipleComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a catchComplete operator that I use from time to time

#### The catchComplete operator

This operator functions very similarly to catchError, only it functions over `complete` instead of `error` messages. This lets you chain a new observable into the completion of a previous observable.

```js
function catchComplete<T, R>(fn: () => Observable<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T|R> {
  return s => concat(s, defer(fn));
}
```

#### Operator in Use

I would say this is a much cleaner solution than using `defaultIfEmpty`

```js
function removeMultipleComponent(paths: string[]): Observable<any> {
  if (paths.length > 1) {
    return removeComponent(path[0]).pipe(
      catchComplete(() => removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1))
    );
  }
  return removeComponent(path[0]);
}
```

#### Aside: How I would implement removeMultipleComponent

This doesn't really require recursion. You already have a list of all the paths, so you can just map them into your removeComponent calls and then subscribe to them one at a time with concat. This should be identical to what you've done above. It doesn't care whether `removeComponent` calls emit anything, only that they do eventually complete (Again, same as above).

```js
function removeComponent(path: string): Observable<any> {
    ...
    // This method returns an observable with some result if the component is removed.
    // But, just complete in some cases.
}

function removeMultipleComponent(paths: string[]): Observable<any> {\
  return concat(
    ...paths.map(removeComponent)
  );
}
```

#### The catchEmpty operator

This operator functions very similarly to `catchComplete`, only it will only catch a completed stream that has never emitted any values.

Here's a first draft that should work:

```js
function catchEmpty<T, R>(fn: () => Observable<R>): OperatorFunction<T, T|R> {
  return s => defer(() => {
    let count = 0;
    return concat(
      s.pipe(tap(() => count++)),
      defer(() => count === 0? fn() : EMPTY)
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catchComplete operator. 
Just right after I've solved the issue with the defaultIfEmpty, I realized that the concat is more than enough for me :) 

  `deleteMultipleComponent(pathsToRemove: string[]): Observable<string> { return concat(...pathsToRemove.map(path => this.deleteDashboardComponent(path).pipe(mapTo(path))));}`

Anyway. Thanks for your answer. That's the most relevant answer.

Comment: Just to make that more suitable for this task, I think the catchComplete should be catchEmpty for this case. I have an idea, how can it be solved, but I'm really looking forward for your solution. Can you add a catchEmpty implementation as well to your answer?

Comment: I've included a cursory implementation for catchEmpty, though I can almost guarantee that if you're using this, you're probably making things more complicated than you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`finalize`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator, but in that case other operators would be ignored since technically the source observable has completed.

Note: `finalize` will also be triggered when source observable emits an error.

```js
function removeMultipleComponent(paths: string[]): Observable <string> {
  if (paths.length > 1) {
    return removeComponent(path[0]).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        // do something when source completes
      }),
      switchMapTo(
        of (paths[0]),
        removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1))
      )
    );
  }
  return removeComponent(path[0]);
}
```

#### Update: `repeatWhen`

You could use `repeatWhen` to trigger the source observable again when it completes.

```js
function removeMultipleComponent(paths: string[]): Observable <string> {
  if (paths.length > 1) {
    return removeComponent(path[0]).pipe(
      repeatWhen(value => 
        value.pipe(switchMap(_ => removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1)))
      )
      switchMapTo(
        of (paths[0]),
        removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1))
      )
    );
  }
  return removeComponent(path[0]);
}
```

Comment: What I would like to do is something like:
      catchComplete(() => {
        return removeMultipleComponent(paths.slice(1));
      })

Comment: Yes replacing your "`catchComplete`" with `finalize` would do it. But the real question is, do you wish to chain the following `swithcMapTo` even when the source completes? Because like I said, `finalize` would ignore it since the source observable has completed.

Comment: Where is the return within the finalize ? :) I don't want to stop process. Finalize is just a void function.

Comment: @Duba: In that case you could try to use `repeatWhen`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [`defaultIfEmpty`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/defaultifempty) operator. That way you always have always something emitted before completion. You can then check for that default value in the other stream to handle this special case.

```js
function removeComponent(path: string): Observable<any> {
    return yourOriginalObservable.pipe(
        defaultIfEmpty('DEFAULT') // or any other value you like
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That defaultIsEmpty was that I looked for.

I will update the question with the solution based on your answer.